# Use of angle brackets in telepathically transmitted speech

Tags: punctuation

I've recently started the novel "Polar City Blues" by Katharine Kerr and found this interesting use of angle brackets for telepathically transmitted text:

[image: picture of text]

This roughly translates as (from context)

> "Little brother, you should tell Lacy. There was a strong, evil force which I heard telepathically back there. There was a murder of a Carli and you were with your police friend."
>
> "I don't remember. How can I tell Lacy?"

**Is this an established (even if esoteric) use of angle brackets? Or something particular to this author?**

---

(Apologies if this is not on topic, happy to repost somewhere else if it is)

Comment: At least your own interpretation seems spot on. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket),

> Chevrons [angle brackets] are infrequently used to denote words that are thought instead of spoken…

So it is a recognized method of distinguishing between thought and speech. It's rare, but appropriate nonetheless.

Comment: Good catch, although this is not surrounded by brackets, it kind of feels like the author is trying to express something more than just thought.